# Running an MVC Application as a Sub-Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am facing problem in creating an mvc application as sub-application of the asp.net application. My Mvc application is doing fine in development environment and even when it is deployed normally. However whenever I tried to deploy it as a sub-application of an asp.net application like http://mainapplication/mvcsubapplication I got an error

```
The view 'Index' or its master could not be found. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
```

There is no problem in view naming since application is well tested in development environment. It only happens when I tried to deploy it as sub-app. remember I am deploying on a server with IIS 7.x installed on it. Any response will be appreciated. Thanx

Comment: I think its becuase mvc looks for view in Root of virtual directory ie ~/Views  ,

Comment: I have tried by putting the Views folder at the root but still in vain. I also tried paths like ~/subfolder/Views/ where subfolder is the folder name of my sub-app. It still did not work for me. 
I then tried to verify the Absolute path of the view through 
HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Views/Home/Index.aspx"); which gives
c:/web/rootfolder/subfolder/Views/Home/Index.aspx So do u have any idea whats going wrong

Comment: Did you ever find the answer? Having the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

When you say "Sub-Application", are you just trying to run the site in a folder? If so, can you not mark the folder as an "Application" in IIS? This would cause the "root" to be inside your subfolder, so everything should work normally.

If you need the Application root to be the parent folder, then I'd suggest moving your code into a similar structure locally, and fixing up the Routes/etc. to work from there.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and it is deployed as an application... not just a virtual directory.